# Possible to use my own search for Amazon

Tags: php

Is it possible to use my own search code to search Amazon with my Amazon affiliate id. I have this code from long ago I tried to convert to Amazon but it did not work.

```
<form class="tfnewsearch" action="https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=assoc_res_sw_ca_dka_cra_t0_view_all?field-keywords=<?php echo $_REQUEST['q']?>&search-alias=aps&tag=capebretons0b-20&linkCode=w13&linkId= method="get">
```

>

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im not even sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form class="tfnewsearch" action="https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=assoc_res_sw_ca_dka_cra_t0_view_all?field-keywords=<?php echo $_REQUEST['q']?>&search-alias=aps&tag=capebretons0b-20&linkCode=w13&linkId= method="get">
<input type="text" id="tfq" class="tftextinput4" name="q" size="21" maxlength="12000" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What are you looking for?" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['q'])) echo " value='{$_REQUEST['q']}'"?>>
<input type="submit" value="" class="tfbutton4">
</form>
```